# Extracting Statistics from Duplicate Records

Tags: sqlite

I'm looking to get some fairly simple statistics from groups of duplicate records in a csv file. (The stats are simple, but pulling them is more challenging.)

I'm hoping to get some help putting together some sqlite code that will help me do this. The best way for me to be able to explain what I'm trying to do is through examples.

Example 1

```
Line | Duplicate Id | Created by | Company Name | Account Owner | Created by Team | Owner Team
 1     rbt1546        John Smith   SMR Inc.       John Smith      Inside Sales      Inside Sales
 2     rbt1546        John Smith   SMR Corp       John Smith      Inside Sales      Inside Sales
 3     mnd1452        Jen Davis    RMX Inc.       Rob Diaz        Lead Gen          Inside Sales
 4     mnd1452        John Smith   RMX Inc.       Rob Diaz        Inside Sales      Inside Sales
 5     mnd1452        Jen Davis    RMX            John Smith      Lead Gen          Inside Sales
```

In the example above we have two examples where duplicate accounts were created by the same person. (We will call these cases "own goals".) John Smith scored 1 own goal (line 2) and so did Jen Davis (line 5). In this data set, 1 own goal was created by Inside sales and 1 was created by the lead gen team. (These are the stats I'm looking to pull from 62,000 rows of data in my csv.)

I'm not sure where to begin when it comes to writing sqlite queries on a problem of this nature.

What is the best way to go at this?

Comment: Please read the info provided at the full tag description of the tag you used. I.e. follow the "view tag" link and then the "Learn more" link.

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain with which symptoms it failed.

Comment: It is unclear what your questions is. At a guess you know the `join` and have trouble using it, but you need to explain about that. Currently the question gives a strong impression of "give the code please", which is not considered a question on StackOverflow. Please provide a [mre] as described in the tag info, which demonstrates your best attempt at using `join` on this, or whatever is your best attempt at writing any query towards your goal. That way you can focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the duplicate accounts created by the same person then you can do it with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DuplicateId, Createdby ORDER BY Line) rn
  FROM tablename
) 
WHERE rn > 1
```

If there is some other column instead of `Line` like a Date that denotes the order of the creation of the accounts then use that column in `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

This may just be a case of simple aggregates:

For counts of own goals, it looks like you are saying anything beyond the first record is the start of your count of duplicates, so I’m using count(*) -1 as the count of goals:

```
SELECT duplicateid, createdby, count(*)-1 as count_own_goals
FROM    tablename
GROUP BY duplicateid, createdby
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

For counts of team goals:

```
SELECT duplicateid, createdbyteam, count(*)-1 as count_team_goals
FROM    tablename
GROUP BY duplicateid, createdbyteam
HAVING count(*) > 1
```